# Trouble Writing to App Group Container Directory via ArchiveByteStream in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm encountering an issue when trying to write to the App Group Container Directory in iOS using ArchiveByteStream method. Previously, I successfully used SSZipArchive to unzip a file into this directory, as shown in the following code:

```
static func unzipDatFilesToAssetDirectory() {
        let archiveFileName = "Archive.zip"
        guard let sourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: archiveFileName, withExtension: nil) else {
            LogService.shared.logCritical("Failed to find \(archiveFileName) in the bundle")
            return
        }
        do {
            try SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: sourceURL.path, toDestination: TGConstant.assetDirectory.path, overwrite: true, password: nil)
            LogService.shared.logInfo("Successfully unzipped \(archiveFileName) to \(TGConstant.assetDirectory.path)")
        } catch {
            LogService.shared.logCritical("Error unzipping \(archiveFileName) to \(TGConstant.assetDirectory.path): \(error)")
        }
    }
```

However, when attempting a similar operation with Apple Archive LZMA to compress an archive (reducing it from 4MB to 2MB), I'm facing issues. Here's the method I wrote for this purpose:

```
static func unpackDatFilesToAssetDirectory() {
        let archiveFileName = "archive.aar"
        guard let sourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: archiveFileName, withExtension: nil) else {
            LogService.shared.logCritical("DAT: Failed to find \(archiveFileName) in the bundle")
            return
        }
        let sourcePath = sourceURL.path
        let archiveFilePath = FilePath(sourcePath)

        guard let readFileStream = ArchiveByteStream.fileStream(
                path: archiveFilePath,
                mode: .readOnly,
                options: [ ],
                permissions: FilePermissions(rawValue: 0o644)) else {
            LogService.shared.logCritical("DAT: Unable to create readFileStream.")
            return
        }
        let destinationFilePath = FilePath(TGConstant.assetDirectory.path)

        LogService.shared.logInfo("DAT: Source path: \(sourcePath)")
        LogService.shared.logInfo("DAT: Destination path: \(TGConstant.assetDirectory.path)")

        guard let writeFileStream = ArchiveByteStream.fileStream(
                path: destinationFilePath,
                mode: .writeOnly,
                options: [ .create ],
                permissions: FilePermissions(rawValue: 0o644)) else {
            LogService.shared.logCritical("DAT: Unable to create writeFileStream.")
            return
        }
        guard let decompressStream = ArchiveByteStream.decompressionStream(readingFrom: readFileStream) else {
            LogService.shared.logCritical("DAT: Unable to create decompress stream.")
            return
        }
        do {
            _ = try ArchiveByteStream.process(readingFrom: decompressStream,
                                              writingTo: writeFileStream)
            LogService.shared.logInfo("DAT: Successfully uncompressed \(archiveFileName) to \(TGConstant.assetDirectory.path)")
        } catch {
            LogService.shared.logCritical("DAT: Error uncompressing \(archiveFileName) to \(TGConstant.assetDirectory.path): \(error)")
        }
        defer {
            try? decompressStream.close()
            try? writeFileStream.close()
            try? readFileStream.close()
        }
    }
```

This method fails with the following error message:

> CRITICAL FileManagerHelper.unpackDatFilesToAssetDirectory():66 - DAT:
> Unable to create writeFileStream.

My question is, why can SSZipArchive write to the App Group Container Directory successfully, but my custom method using ArchiveByteStream.fileStream fails? I suspect it might be related to file permissions, but I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This `FilePath(TGConstant.assetDirectory.path)` doesn't look right. Don't you want a path involving `FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.myName.appName")` ?